# Form won't submit with jQuery submit() method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, jquery-mobile

I need to close an iFrame after the form within the iFrame was submitted, which I got with this function:

iFrame

```
$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(event) {
    setTimeout(parent.closeIFrame('#popupAddComment{{ poiID }}-popup'), 500);
});
```

Main

```
function closeIFrame(iframe){
    $(iframe).remove();
    location.reload(true);
}
```

This works fine, even though my Chrome Browser (Version 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit)) won't wait the given time but fires the function instantly.

The problem I can't solve now is that the form will not be submitted to the PHP Symfony2 backend since I implemented the jQuery `submit()` method.

I did a bit of research and found a possible solution

iFrame

```
$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.submit();
    setTimeout(parent.closeIFrame('#popupAddComment{{ poiID }}-popup'), 5000);
});
```

Sadly this won't work neither. Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Comment: The browser closes the frame immediately because you're telling it to. You're calling the function right there as a parameter to `setTimeout()` instead of passing in a *function* to do it. (No timeout will be established because the `closeIFrame` function returns `undefined`, and because it reloads the whole page anyway - which is kind-of weird; what's the point of doing anything to the DOM if you're reloading the whole page?)

Comment: If you are going to `submit` the form then why `event.preventDefault();this.submit();`? It will be submitted automatically.

Comment: @Patrick2607 if I use `$(this)` the form won't submit and the close function won't work either.

Comment: @Pointy I reload the page because the customer wants to see the form data from the iframe instantly. The data of the form will be displayed on the parent site. The system is to old and fragile to use ajax magic whatsoever.

Comment: @b0s3 I tried it because I've seen a post with this as a possible solution to the problem (show your research done)

Comment: If you want to post a form and have the results show up, then just use ordinary, no-JavaScript-needed form posting.

Comment: @Pointy I'd love to, but I can't because it's a really old jQuery Mobile application. I wish I could do it, but I can't do it systemwise and the customer doesn't want it too.